# Why an old material can certified as a patent?

Tags: patentability, cn103666378

Many companies such as Climator "http://www.climator.com/files/products/climsel-c58.pdf" resolve the supper cooling, conductivity, separation and other problems of sodium acetate trihydrate within passed 20 years. Why this patent "Publication number   CN103666378 A" can certified?

Answer (score 1):

That document CN103666378 A is patent application submitted to China's patent office. The A at the end, by international convention, means it is a *publication of an application*. That document is *not* a granted patent. From its page at google/patents (reachable by the link on the right) it looks like it is the only publication so far.